# Meteorjs events on new dom element

Tags: events, dom, meteor

I have got a problem with events , I add new element on template from client and when I try to catch click event on this element it does not work , is there any solution for that ?  Thanks

Comment: I forgot to say , I also tried .rendered method for this but it doesn't work also

Comment: Can you show us an example of your code for context

Comment: I think it was a wrong element id problem  i tried again and it works know , sorry for this